# jQuery callback function not working for cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using 
nodejs in backend at localhost:3000
and 
http Apache server at localhost:8080

```
$.post("http://localhost:3000", {data:"data"}, function(){alert("hurrah");}); 
// that one not working
$.get("http://localhost:3000", {data:"data"}, function(){alert("hurrah");}); 
// is working, but callback function not working
```

Comment: Any errors? If you get CORS error, no callback will be fired even if server sends 200 response.

Comment: You have to check whether the server is sending the response or not. Check there in the server.

Comment: @Justinas if he is getting the get then how can client throw CORS?

Comment: @ullas in node js app, simple response, "res.send("data");" using express js

Comment: You need to send `CORS` headers from your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out [Cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) for NodeJS?

Cross Domain requests may be blocked to your web server and if you're running NodeJS, you can add Cors(), configure the content you wish to accept (or accept all for the sake of debugging / time at the moment).

Depending on your NodeJS configuration you can set this up by including it at the top of your main class.

A default configuration, using [Express](https://expressjs.com/) might look something like this... (note this accepts all content!)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Listening on 8080');
});
```

Comment: thanks, now $.get working with callback function too, but, still $.post not working

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) ?
May I suggest using `Ajax`

You can form a post using this... (thanks jQuery docs!)

`$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});`

Comment: Also, would you mind posting the code from the NodeJS side of things, as in the route for `GET` and `POST` please!